# Twitch.tv and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

I'm trying to build a twitch tv chat app on the serverside. I tried a dirty include of their js API using fs. Seems like this doesnt work. Has anyone managed to get the twitchtv client side app working on server? I pretty much just want access to their chat so that I can parse stuff.

```
var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.readFileSync('twitch.min.js')+'');

Twitch.init({clientId: 'XXXX'}, function(error, status) {
    console.log("Twitch initialized!");
});
```

Comment: The issue seems to be that the API is referencing window, which obviously doesnt exist serverside. Any way to get around this?

Comment: It would be best if you could use a library that was designed to be server-side.  Maybe you want to have a look at [node-twitchtv](https://github.com/jbueza/node-twitchtv).

Comment: Found out that twitch chat can be accessed by IRC. Using the irc package to get access to chat. Thanks anyways!